# Matlab find all files with text in its name

Tags: matlab

There are two patterns of naming files in my directory.

Pattern 1:

```
'XXXXXX FixedCost_zz123.mat'
```

Pattern 2

```
'XXXXXX FixedVolume.mat'
```

So, based on above some examples of real files in my folder are:

```
'Sap FixedCost_pkz123.mat'
'ASDFG FixedCost_z1.mat'
'TUP112RA FixedCost_h1453.mat'
'as FixedVolume.mat'
'P1234L FixedVolume.mat'
'afg FixedVolume.mat'
```

I want to be able to find all files of 'FixedCost' and 'FixedVolume' type based on what I need at any instance. How do I achieve this ? My input to the function would be either 'FixedCost' or 'FixedVolume'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `dir` function with an argument specifying a filename pattern:

```
fixedCostFiles = dir('*FixedCost*.mat');
fixedVolumeFiles = dir('*FixedVolume.mat');
```

If you want more sophisticated selections and are not afraid of java you could also use the apache FileUtils, they come as part of MATLAB's java:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Specifically, check the `listFiles` function.

Comment: How do I add directory structure to it if I want to provide the user the option to enter any drive he wants to use and hence the directory structure would be another input to the function.

Comment: In that case, prefix the filename-pattern with the directory `dir("path/to/files/*FixedCost*.mat")` - as in MatteoD's answer.

Answer (score 3):

This will return all the files with a specific wildcard in the name

```
file_list_1 = dir(fullfile(directory_path, '*FixedVolume*.mat'))
file_list_2 = dir(fullfile(directory_path, '*FixedCost_zz123*.mat'))
```

Answer (score 0):

matlab has regex if you need something more complex 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html

also see the  "match" or "tokens" options